# Swift удаление ячейки из поиска

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть таблица и есть поиск(searchBar) к ней, есть два массива, один основной, другой для фильтра поиска. Вопрос в том, что я хочу удалить ячейку при этом удалить данные из основного массива. Удаляя из таблицы - все хорошо, но если ввести запрос в поиск и и попытаться удалить, то как ни пробовал, не могу удалить именно из основного массива, а не из фильтрованного. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому поможет, решил это так.

```
let boo = filteredDataMy[indexPath.row]
let farray = myGamesArray.filter {$0 != boo}
            myGamesArray = farray

            filteredDataMy = myGamesArray
```

Берем indexPath.row ячейки из поиска, далее фильтруем и убираем из основного массива значение взятое из ячейки в поиске. Приравниваем основной массив к фильтрованному. И массив отвечающий за поиск приравниваем к основному.